# Using firebase UI in modal dialog in shiny

Tags: r, firebase, shiny, bslib

I have the following app that works for sign in but the modal dialog does not show the firebase UI after signing out. How do I make it show the sign in buttons after signing out:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(firebase)
library(bslib)

# Firebase project configuration ------------------------------------------

firebase::firebase_config(api_key = "API_KEY",
                          project_id = "PROJECT_ID",
                          app_id = "APP_ID",
                          overwrite = TRUE)



# define signin
signin <- modalDialog(
  title = "Welcome. Please Sign in.",
  # useFirebase(),
  firebaseUIContainer(),
  footer = NULL
)


ui_dashboard <- page_navbar(

  title = "title",
  sidebar = sidebar("Sidebar"),
  nav_panel("P1", "Page 1 content"),
  nav_panel("P2", "Page 2 content"),
  nav_panel("P3", "Page 3 content"),
  nav_panel("P4", "Page 4 content"),

  ## Space between sections and sign out button
  nav_spacer(),
  ## Sign out button
  nav_item(
    uiOutput("sign_out_button")
  )
)


ui <- page_fillable(
  useFirebase(),
  shiny::uiOutput("logged_in_ui", fill = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  showModal(signin)

  f <- FirebaseUI$new()$set_providers(
    email = TRUE,
    google = TRUE)$launch()

  observe({
    f$req_sign_in()
    removeModal()
  })

  output$sign_out_button <- shiny::renderUI({
    f$req_sign_in()
    actionButton("signout", "Sign out")
  })


  observeEvent(input$signout, {
    f$sign_out()

    # Show the modal dialog
    showModal(signin)
  })

  output$logged_in_ui <- shiny::renderUI({
    f$req_sign_in()
    ui_dashboard
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```